# Как в C# (не ASP.Net) реализовать обработку файла на удалённой сервере?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, сервер, сеть, обработка

Желательно пример кода с комментариями, но и различные ссылки с информацией об этом не помешают. Такое ведь возможно реализовать ?

Поясню: обрабатывать файл - есть сайт, на который загружается файл(по средству страницы), есть ли возможность при помощи программы передать на этот сайт файл ?

Comment: Что конкретно имеется ввиду под "обработкой файла"? Поясните.

Comment: Смотря как проводить обработку на стороне сервера или локально (загружая файл в локальный каталог), но в любом случае я бы использовал WCF http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd456779.aspx

Comment: А в чём проблема? Отсылаете файл и инструкции по обработке на сервер, там обрабатываете, присылаете назад — где сложность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно посредством [сокета](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b6xa24z5.aspx) создать приложение клиент-сервер. [ССЫЛЬ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w89fhyex.aspx)